# Cannot initialize a "share" Git repository in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: git, ubuntu

In my Ubuntu terminal, I create an empty Git repository in an empty folder, say called "Docs", on a removable hard disk. But the system response me an error message to my command

```
$ git --bared init --shared
fatal: Could not make /media/HARDDISK/Docs/refs/heads writable by group
```

I tried different options for "share", e.g., group and all. But it does not work. The initialization works if I remove the `--share` argument.

Comment: how about `sudo git --bared init --share` ?

Comment: It does not work also...

Comment: same error ? can you show the permission of the folder / path ?

Comment: Yes, the same error...Can I please ask how to show the permission? Thanks!

Comment: isn't `--bare` and `--shared`?

Comment: `ls -al /media/HARDDISK/Docs/refs/heads`

Comment: The permission is drwx.

Comment: No, not "--shared".

Comment: You say this is on a removable disk. What filesystem is it using? Does that filesystem support changing these permissions?

Comment: If it's on a removable hard disk, it might be a FAT partition which doesn't support group permissions.

Comment: It's definitely --bare and --shared just like @gipi said. See [git-init man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html)

Comment: @gipi sorry, you're right. It's "shared". I did a typo in posting the question. Thanks!

Comment: @jszakmeister It's FAT partition. Can I please ask is there any solution to this problem? Git on FAT partition works in Windows and Mac OS X...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably must be the superuser otherwise you can't change the group permissions.

On ubuntu try

```
$ sudo git --bare init --shared /path/to/repo
```